# Brand new Pi not displaying video

Tags: video, hdmi, raspbian-wheezy

I just got a new 512 Pi and plugged it in to my TV using HDMI. On first boot everything was working properly and I made it to the config window. On the config window I turned SSH on and then tried the update option. It threw some errors and then went to a blank black screen that I could type on, but not execute any command, so I unplugged the power.

My problem is that now once the power is plugged back in, nothing happens. The PWR light goes on, but that is it. I have tried HDMI as well as the RCA jack with no luck.
I reformatted my card and reloaded a clean version of wheezy onto it.

Did I make a rookie mistake or is there a bigger issue at play here? Thanks.

Comment: If you formatted the card completely new and correctly, it should work. You could try formatting it like a new SD-card you would use on a pc, then make a new version of wheezy on it. Make sure you do everything right, search for a tutorial for your OS (linux/mac/windows). Also try first expand_rootfs and then update. SSH is enabled on first boot. Try SSH to test the Pi. Check that your Display is displaying HDMI input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to have been the card. I'm not sure how or why, because it WAS working. But I just picked up a new sdhc card and everything is in working order now. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Had you added any extra repositories to /etc/apt/sources.list?

When I was playing around with mine initially, I did that and the following update/upgrade resulted in nothing working, including video on the subsequent reboot, as it had (presumably) downloaded non-Pi versions of some of the base software.

Re-imaging fixed everything up for me.